Changing gear usage of Rohloff gears
I have a R&M Homage with Rohloff e-14 gears. I find I really just use gears 7 - 14. Can sprockets be changed so I would mainly use gears 4 - 11??

Only riding in the high gears is tempting on an e-bike, but risks wearing out your components faster, particularly the expensive Rohloff hub. It is advisable to use the lower gears for starting from a stop or riding uphill, just like with a car.

You should probably check the Rohloff manual to check the maximum allowed ratio that is supported, or ask your local bike shop

“the working efficiency of the Rohloff SPEEDHUB 500/14 is brought up to 96% (for gears #1 to #7) and 98% (for gears #8 to #14). ” Efficiency wise it’s actually a good thing if you are using the higher gears. Preferably gear 11 because it’s the direct gear with close to 99% efficiency: https://www.rohloff.de/fileadmin/_migrated/pics/image014.en.jpg

Puzzling why you have a Rohloff if you never use the lower gears. The wide gear ratios are the Rohloff's speciality.

It was supplied as standard with my Homage and I find the gears great - I do use the lower ones but only sparingly and if the ratios were higher they would get used more.
